# I cannot reproduce a geometric result algebraically

Tags: inequality, analytic-geometry, geometric-inequalities

> Take a parabola $u(x)=ax^2 + bx + c$, where $a<0$, and draw a secant on an upward-sloping portion of the parabola from $(w-h, u(w-h))$ to $(w+h, u(w+h))$, for some $w \leq -\frac b{2a} - |h|$. Now find $x=\gamma$ such that $u(\gamma ) = \frac 12(u(w+h) + u(w-h))$. Prove that $\gamma < w$.

This is represented geometrically as

[image: sketch]

so can you see that it is obvious that $\gamma < w$?

However, I wanted to prove this algebraically, but I couldn't. I started off by finding the value for $\gamma $ in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$, $w$,  and  $h$.
\begin{align*}
a\gamma^2 + b\gamma + c &= \frac 12 \left(a(w+h)^2 + b(w+h) + c\right) + \frac 12 \left(a(w-h)^2 + b(w-h) + c\right)\\
 &= a\left( w^2 + h^2\right) + bw + c \\
\gamma &= \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2 + 4a\left(a\left(w^2 + h^2\right)+ bw\right)}}{2a} \end{align*}
I tried playing with the inequalities, but I couldn't get it to work (I could only get an upper bound of $-\frac b{2a} + |h|$). I at least wanted to prove that the lower value of $\gamma$ is not correct, due to the restriction $\gamma > w - |h|$.

Comment: Your calculation shows that $u(\gamma) \lt u(w)$.  Since $u$ is increasing, that implies $\gamma \lt w$.

Comment: @FredH correct. Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: Because you did most of the work.  I think you should post it yourself.

Comment: @FredH Comments are for comments. Answer posts are for answers. What you have there is an answer, however brief it may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have 
$$
u(\gamma) = a\gamma^2 + b\gamma + c \\
= aw^2 + bw + c + ah^2\\
= u(w) + ah^2<u(w)
$$
right there. Together with the fact that $u$ is increasing we get $\gamma < w$.